# how to change the wireless network from the application?

Tags: java, android

I want to connect to a specific network (according to the network's name) from the app. 
This is so the user doesn't need to open the system's networks-list.
If this is not possible, how to open the system's networks list from the app.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to ask the user to select a network from within the app. Simply allow your app to use the network to which the phone is connected already. To do this, you need to add network permissions.

Here you have everything you need :
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Comment: You may have misunderstood my question.
I don't see anything there that enables me to change the network that the Tablet is using.

Comment: You have initially mentioned: how to open the system's networks list from the app. What app are you referring to?

Comment: The problem is that the device (tablet) may be connected to another network in the list, or maybe not connected at all.
I want to be able to connect it from my Android app so he doesn't need to open the System's Network page (list of networks).